# TestDome SQL test on Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I'm trying to solve this TestDome quiz: in a company, several different programs insert rows into a messages table which should later be parsed and inserted into appropriate tables. Consider the tables:

Table `messages`

```
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
  data VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
```

Table `notifications`

```
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  message VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
```

Table `alerts`

```
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  shortMessage VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
```

Create a procedure called `ParseMessages` in the default schema which should do the following for all rows in the messages table:

- Insert all rows where the type is 'notification' to the `notifications` table with the `message` column being set to the `data` column of `messages` table.
- Insert all rows where the type is 'alert' to the alerts table with the `shortMessage` column being set to the first 15 characters of the `data` column of the `messages` table.

In both cases the `id` column should be the same as in the `messages` column.

You can find the body here: https://www.testdome.com/questions/60310

My code is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ParseMessages
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO notifications (id, message)
            SELECT m.id, m.data
            FROM messages m
            WHERE m.type = 'notification' 
              AND m.id NOT IN (SELECT n.id FROM notifications n)
    END;
      
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO alerts (id, shortMessage)
            SELECT m.id, SUBSTRING(m.data, 0, 15)
            FROM messages m
            WHERE m.type = 'alert' 
              AND m.id NOT IN (SELECT n.id FROM alerts n)
    END;
END
GO


EXEC ParseMessages
```

But I only get 50%, can you tell why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use the transaction for the accuracy of the information

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ParseMessages
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY 
        BEGIN TRAN
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO notifications (id, message)
                    SELECT m.id, m.data
                    FROM messages m
                    WHERE m.type = 'notification' 
                      AND m.id NOT IN (SELECT n.id FROM notifications n)
            END;
      
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO alerts (id, shortMessage)
                    SELECT m.id, SUBSTRING(m.data, 0, 15)
                    FROM messages m
                    WHERE m.type = 'alert' 
                      AND m.id NOT IN (SELECT n.id FROM alerts n)
            END;
        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    END CATCH 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The start position of string should be 1, not 0. So it should be:

**SELECT m.id, SUBSTRING(m.data, 1, 15)**

Answer (score 0):

**You can use CAST(data AS VARCHAR(15))**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ParseMessages
AS
BEGIN
  insert into notifications (id, message) select id, data from messages where type = 'notification'
  insert into alerts (id, shortMessage) select id, CAST(data AS VARCHAR(15))  from messages where type = 'alert'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ParseMessages AS
BEGIN
  -- Insert notifications
  INSERT INTO notifications (id, message)
  SELECT id, data
  FROM messages
  WHERE type = 'notification';
  
  -- Insert alerts
  INSERT INTO alerts (id, shortMessage)
  SELECT id, SUBSTR(data, 1, 15)
  FROM messages
  WHERE type = 'alert';
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**